# How to add an input tag to a table using JQuery in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Today I stumbled across this problem when I try to dynamically add an input tag to a row in a table.

"SyntaxErrpr: missing ) after argument list"

The code I used:

```php
//creates a input element based on the fieldname, fieldvalue and fieltype.

public function createInput($aFieldName, $aFieldValue, $aInputType)
{   
    echo '<script>';
    echo '$("#TableContainer tr:last").';
    echo    'append($("<tr><td>"'.$aFieldName.'"</td><td><input type="'.$aInputType.'" name= "'.$aFieldName.'"></td></tr>"));';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

**edit**

input:

```
fieldname = classnumber,
fieldvalue = classnumber,
inputetype = text,
```

[Output](http://collabedit.com/qxgva)

When I use it without using the variables it somehow works and doesn't give me the error mentioned above.

```php
//creates a input element based on the fieldname, fieldvalue and fieltype.
public function createInput($aFieldName, $aFieldValue, $aInputType)
{   
    echo '<script>';
    echo '$("#TableContainer tr:last").';
    echo    'append($("<tr><td>test</td><td><input type=\"test\" name=\"test\"></td></tr>"));';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

**edit**

[Output](http://collabedit.com/qxgva)

Comment: Are the variables escaped/sanitized?

Comment: yes those variables are escaped.

Comment: can you post your generated table with input

Comment: Edited the original post